# qsort for sorting an array of objects

Tags: c++, quicksort

I'm trying to use the qsort() to sort an array of object pointers (PointP = Point*)
attached is the compare function and the sorting, The problem is that nothing happens and sorting doesn't occur.

```
int compareByAngleP(const void* elem1,const void* elem2) {
    PointP point1 = (PointP) elem1;
    PointP point2 = (PointP) elem2;
    if (abs(point1->getAngle() - point2->getAngle())>0.001)
    {
        return point1->getAngle() - point2->getAngle();
    }
    return  point1->getY() - point2->getY();
}

void sortArrayP(PointP* array, int size) {
    qsort(array,size, sizeof(PointP), compareByAngleP);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the `void*`?

Comment: If `array` is indeed the base-address of a sequence of `PointP`, then your params are not setup correctly in your comparator. You're missing one level of indirection.

Answer (score 4):

My *advice* would be to forget about `std::qsort`, favour plain old `std::sort`. Unlike `std::qsort` it is typesafe and in most implementations much faster.

```
std::sort(array, array+size, compareByAngleP);
```

And do rid of the `void*` in the compare function in favour of actual types.

Furthermore, if you are using C++11 and the array is local simply:

```
std::sort(std::begin(array), std::end(array), compareByAngleP);
```

Or even better just use a `std::vector` or other most approitaite container.

```
std::vector<Point> array { ... };
std::sort(array.begin(), array.end(), compareByAngleP);
```

### Note

You may need to amend your comparison function so that it returns ​true if the first argument is less than the second. (or simply implement `operator <` for Point).

### References

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: I'm not allowed to use c++11 or vectors :-(

Comment: and if i change void* to Point* then qsort() claims that the arguments don't match

Comment: :/, you can still use std::sort as I have shown in the first example.

Comment: @YuvalCohen I am suggesting you DON'T use `std::qsort` but `std::sort`.

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems in your use of `qsort` and in your comparison function.

1. `qsort` will use `memcpy` (or similar) to re-order the elements of the array. If your `Point` type has a copy-constructor (or a member that has one), then using `qsort` on it is asking for trouble (it results in Undefined Behaviour).
2. Your `compareByAngleP` function is not suitable for sorting, because the relation it checks is not transitive.
   For example, if you have three points `A`, `B` and `C`, all with the same `Y` coordinate and respectively with the angles `10.000`, `10.001` and `10.002`, then `compareByAngeP` will indicate that `A == B` and `B == C`, but `A != C`, which can cause havoc for a sorting function.

Answer (score 1):

Following qsort reference (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort) 3rd parameter of qsort should be 'size of each element in the array in bytes' so instead

```
qsort(array,size, sizeof(PointP), compareByAngleP);
```

try

```
qsort(array,size, sizeof(PointP*), compareByAngleP);
```

Also you are implicity casting float to int (while returning value from comparing function). But:

```
(int)0.2 == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you return bool instead of int from Compare function, then something different will happen.